# How to systematically find the domain of this funtion (with respect to $a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

This problem is killing me, I don't know how to systematically find the domain of:

$$ f(x) = \frac{2e^{\frac{1}{2x}}-a}{\sqrt{a^2-1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}}$$

I am stuck specifically on how to determine for which $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$a^2-1+e^{\frac{1}{x}} \geq 0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually needed that $$a^2 -1 +e^{1/x} \gt 0$$ to prevent dividing by zero. This is $$e^{1/x} \gt 1-a^2 $$ Now, if $1-a^2 \le 0 \iff |a| \ge 1$ then this inequality is always true and the domain is the set of all reals. Otherwise, take the natural log and use that it is an increasing function: $$\frac 1x \gt \ln (1-a^2) $$

If $\ln(1-a^2)=0 \iff a=0$, the domain is $(0,\infty)$ as in that case you need $\frac 1x \gt 0$.

Otherwise, $\ln(1-a^2)\lt 0 \iff 0\lt |a| \lt 1$ and looking at the graph of $\frac 1x$ you can deduce that either $$x\lt \frac{1}{\ln(1-a^2)} $$ or $$x\gt 0$$